# Hide text before dollar sign character in options without removing completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to select part of the string before the dollar sign in the select menu. Right now I am just trying to hide it so it does not appear in the dropdown, but it will be used later so I do not want to simply strip it out because I will need to be able to use it in a variable when the option is selected.

```js
 var seminiars;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>1$5,000</option>
<option>2$10,000</option>
<option>5$100,000</option>
<option>10$500,000</option>
</select>
```

So far I have only been able to remove it completely, but then I was unable to store it and use it when someone selects on of the option.

---

**Side note**: I am unable to edit the html directly, the code is automatically generated.

Comment: Why not use data attribute for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay... I just noticed the side note.

> I am unable to edit the html directly, the code is automatically generated.

The trick here, will be to set a [data value](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for each `option`.

```js
// Run that loop to set the data values for each option
$("select option").each(function() {
  let optionText = $(this).text();
  let textSplit = optionText.split("$")
  $(this).data("before_dolard_sign", textSplit[0])
  $(this).text(textSplit[1])
})

$("select").on("change", function() {
  // So on change, you have access to it
  console.log($(this).find("option:selected").data("before_dolard_sign"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1$5,000</option>
  <option>2$10,000</option>
  <option>5$100,000</option>
  <option>10$500,000</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `value` attribute to store more information not in the text visible to the user. I've added some code below to show how you can get the text or value selected by the user.

If that isn't suitable I've also created a test input and button which helps demonstrate how you can split a string in the way you need to.

The code is fully commented.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

---

```js
// Detect when user changes select option
$("#selectTest").change(function() {

  // Get the text selected by the user
  console.log($("#selectTest option:selected").text());

  // Get the value selected by the user
  console.log($(this).val());

});


// Add click event
$("#splitButton").click(function() {

  // Get input value
  var test = $("#splitTest").val();

  // Split around dollar sign
  var els = test.split("$");

  // Print values to show we did it correctly
  console.log(els[0]);
  console.log("$" + els[1]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectTest">
  <option value="1$5,000">$5,000</option>
  <option value="1$5,000">$10,000</option>
  <option value="5$100,000">$100,000</option>
  <option value="10$500,000">$500,000</option>
</select>

<input id="splitTest" value="10$500,000">
<button id="splitButton">Show Split</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not place this data onto a `data-meta` attribute?

instead of

```html
<option>1$5,000</option>
<option>2$10,000</option>
<option>5$100,000</option>
<option>10$500,000</option>
```

perhaps

```html
<option data-meta="1">$5,000</option>
<option data-meta="2">$10,000</option>
<option data-meta="5">$100,000</option>
<option data-meta="10">$500,000</option>
```

then you can find the `selected` option and use `element.getAttribute("data-meta")` to retrieve the data when you need it

edit: i now see your side-note that you can't edit the html. well, replace it. loop over the html, and use `.split` on the textContent, and move that meta data into an attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use the data attribute to store the info and then run an event listener to retrieve the dataset when selected on change?

```js
const select = document.querySelectorAll('#money');

select.forEach((val) => {
  if (val.value != 'undefined') {
    val.addEventListener('change', () => {
      let data = val.options[val.selectedIndex].dataset['num'];
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="money">
  <option style="display: none;">-->Select an option below<--</option>
  <option data-num='1' class='opt' value='5000'>$5,000</option>
  <option data-num='2' class='opt' value='10000'>$10,000</option>
  <option data-num='5' class='opt' value='100000'>$100,000</option>
  <option data-num='10' class='opt' value='500000'>$500,000</option>
</select>
```